# Is there any difference in solutions between $x^7-1^7=0$ and $x^7-1=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Is there any difference in solutions between $x^7-1^7=0$ and $x^7-1=0$?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: No. $x^7-1^7 = x^7-1^{-2} = x^7 - 1^{17}= x^7-1^{1/2} =x^7-1= .... 0$. (Sorry this comment was reposted here because it had a misleading typo, too late to edit.

Comment: What made you think there might be a difference?

Comment: When ever you have "statement having something to do with A" and you know A = B then you can always rephrase the sentence as "statement having something to do with B" because A and B are the exact same thing.  So $1 = 1^7$.  So $x^7 - 1^7 = x^7 - 1 = x^7 - (564 - 563) = x^7 - (\frac {2+3}{5}) = ......$" etc.

Comment: I found that 1)x^7=1^7,or,x^7=(cos(2kpi+0))+isin(2kpi+0))^7/7,or,(x^7)^1/7=(cos(2kpi)+isin(2kpi)or solutions of x=cos(2kpi)+sin(2kpi)(where k=0,1,..,6) ,but in the second situation, x^7=1,or,(x^7)^1/7=(cos(2kpi)+isin(2kpi))^1/7 so the solution of x=cos(2kpi)/7+isin(2kpi)/7 where k=0,1..6).So,that is my case.

Answer (score 9):

#### Hint:

$$(1)^n=1$$
Where $n$ any real number

Comment: I find this a bit dismissive as an answer to this question. It does not explain anything.

Comment: Um.... what's to explain?  It might not be apparent to the OP $1^7 = 1$ when it is expressed as $x^7 - 1^7$.  The only thing that needs explaining (and this is a hint; not an answer) is that if A = B then f(A) = f(B) because they are the same thing.  The OP probably knows this but doesn't "get" it.  Pointing out the equality is enough of a hint for the OP say ... "oh, yeah...."  If the OP does need to have A= B means they are the same thing then we need a deep discussing on ontology and what the symbol "=" means and how it is not an operator.

Comment: @quid Indeed, but I think this is exactly the answer that the question, as-written, deserved. I have no idea why the OP would ask this, unfortunately.

Comment: @T.Bongers for instance somebody might have made a point in writing $x^7 -1^7 = (x-1)(x^6 + \dots + 1)$  then one might wonder what the point of that was.   "I think this is exactly the answer that the question, as-written, deserved" That's a problematic attitude. Don't answer, or make a serious effort.

Comment: @quid I really wish that the OP had responded to your comment asking *why* they asked the question - but since they didn't, there really isn't much to say beyond "no."

Comment: @T.Bongers That answer is not even a clear "no." It may be unintentional but I find this post rude. // On the non-response, it's not that long ago, and the comment came in a bit late. So I do not see why one would reproach a non-response.

Comment: @quid I'm just lamenting the fact that the OP didn't include the motivation of their question when they originally posted it. I don't find this answer to be rude, personally. (I am completely baffled as to why it received eight upvotes in under an hour, though...)

Comment: @quid, sorry, try to post your answer

Comment: @quid I think that is exactly why the op asked.  In which case $x^7 - 1 = x^7 - 1$ which is *also* $(x-1)(x^6 ..... + 1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And sorry for the possibly uncharitable reading of your answer. In the meantime another answer appeared. If OP replies to my question, I might add another one.

Answer (score 4):

$1 = 1^7$ so "anything to do with $1$" = "anything to do with $1^7$".  So, no, no difference.

I think you are confused because

$x^n - a^n = (x - a)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}a + .... xa^{n-2} + a)=0$

has completely different solutions than

$x^n - a=0 \implies x = $ then $n$-th roots of $a$.

But in this case $1 = 1^7$ and

$x^7 - 1 = 0 \implies x = 1$  (Unless you are doing complex numbers, in which case there are 6 complex solutions.)

Also can be interpreted:

$x^7 - 1^7 = (x -1)(x^6 + x^5*1 + x^4*1^2 + x^3*1^3 + x^2*1^4+x*1^5 + 1^6) =0$

Which can be more easily written

$x^7 - 1 = (x -1)(x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2+x + 1) =0$

So $x = 1$ or $ (x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2+x + 1) =0$

So $x = 1$ as $(x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2+x + 1) =0$ has no real solutions (trust me).

(It does have 6 complex solutions, though, which are the exact same as the complex numbers that solve $x^7 = 1$.  [ trust me].)

Comment: I think that is *the answer*, apart from OP's expectations which are unknown

Comment: IMO, \$\times\$ ( $\times$ ) has always been more clear than $*$.

Answer (score 0):

$1^n=e^{2n\pi i}=cos(2n\pi)+i \cdot sin(2n\pi)$

So 'one' is always 'one' while $n \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: Someone asking this question is going to have absolutely no idea what this answer is about. And I think that explaining arithmetic properties of $1$, which is the multiplicative identity, via complex numbers is completely missing the point.

Comment: @T.Bongers  The question is (and was originally) tagged "complex numbers" and an intro to complex numbers is the most plausible context I can imagine for the question.